# orientdb How to create links in server javascript Functions

Tags: javascript, orientdb

Trying to create links between one vertex record and OUser record. The idea is to have a Person record with addition details about an OUser.

When I try to create a link in a javascript function, I get this error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot drop a property inside a transaction"

I get the error even if I try to create the link in a separate function called after the records have been made. The CREATE LINK command works as expected from the console.
This js recreates the error given a Person vertex class with dbname property:

```
var gdb = orient.getGraph();

var forwardLink = gdb.command("sql","CREATE LINK ouser TYPE LINK FROM Person.dbname TO OUser.name");

gdb.commit();
return
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT: 
The same error is produced when using a SQL function. This is all run from the FUNCTIONS tab in Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
var gdb = orient.getGraphNoTx();

var forwardLink = gdb.command("sql","CREATE LINK ouser TYPE LINK FROM Person.dbname TO OUser.name");

return forwardLink;
```

and I didn't get any errors.

Hope it helps

Regards